# Is there any alternative for * in PHP

Tags: php, html

I need to explode `<TD>`, but in code (I need to extract the data from another website that is not mine). There is `<TD>` with many different attributes, so I can not just write

```
explode("<TD>",$tableA_data[1]));
```

And if I write it like

```
explode("<TD",$tableA_data[1]));
```

without `>` mark, it will put that mark in my result. I tried to remove that mark with

```
str_replace('>',"", $tableA_data);
```

but it does nothing with result.

CODE:

```
$tableA_data = explode('<table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="evidenceUpadcuDetailTable">',$result1);
$tableA_data = str_replace('ALIGN="center" nowrap="nowrap">',"", explode("<TD",$tableA_data[1]));
```

Comment: Try regex. This may be a good starting point http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: @Nouphal.M Never ever ever ever use regex to parse HTML. It is [impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the best option is using a simple HTML parser like [Ganon](https://code.google.com/p/ganon/), I used it in a small project and it works nicely and you could also grab any tag you want.